# How to do 301 redirect for a angularjs website

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, redirect, nginx

We have angularJs website and currently we have a requirement we need to do a 301 redirect from the site for example if user access "A"page mysite.com/A, we need to redirect to mysite.A.com.

Wanted to know what is the best way to handle this situation, should we do in route or .htacess or nginx config. 
Can if you provide a snippet for best option.

Comment: 301 redirects need to be done on the server side. Angular runs on the client and is not capable of this.

Comment: Ok .. Is Ngnix config the best place to handle the redirect ?

Comment: you can use .htaccess if you like

Comment: @HafeezKhan, did my answer solve your question?  If so, I'd appreciate an upvote&&accept.

Comment: Was not able to redirect from .htaccess file, but it worked from ngnix config file

Comment: @HafeezKhan, yes, it's not supposed to work from an .htaccess -- they are very inefficient, and thus not supported by nginx as part of the design; thanks for accept, since it all worked for you, can I get an upvote, too?  you now have a rep of 18, so, you can start upvoting!

Comment: thanks for the upvote!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your [nginx](http://ports.su/www/nginx) server config:

```
location = /A { return  301 http://mysite.A.com/;   }
```

Comment: How about a way to do it WITHOUT modifying your nginx config?

Comment: @thenetimp you cannot issue a 301 redirect from a front-end; and "thanks" for a -1, btw, for not answering something that was never asked, and which is not physically possible to do, either.